# How to automatize the creation of arrows in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automation

I'm creating yet another graph and I don't have particular problems. I can easily create the nodes, assign IDs and create arrows/paths using these IDs. But when there is a lot of content and there is a need of doing the "same work" over and over, I think that many would try to look for a way to do this using some "abbreviation-commands", in order to automatize everything and avoid writing the same code.

So, I am doing something like this:

[image: mock-up image]

Instead of writing `\draw (node) -- (node1);` over and over, changing the ID as I go on, is there a way to tell LaTeX to make as many arrows *"**from** node on the left **to** main node"* as needed?

In case this is not possible (but I trust LaTeX and the experts here), please post an answer stating it, so I can accept it anyway and spare some headache hours to others with my "problem".

So all `A#` nodes must point to the Main node `inf` while the `b#` nodes to the `part` one. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes,arrows,positioning,
  calc}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]

\begin{scope}[node distance=5mm,
                 every node/.style={align=left,text width=10em}]

    \node[draw=none,fill=none] (a1) {acabar de};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a1] (a2) {acabar por};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a2] (a3) {comenzar a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a3] (a4) {darle (a uno) por};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a4] (a5) {deber};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a5] (a6) {deber de};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a6] (a7) {dejar de};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a7] (a8) {echar(se) a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a8] (a9) {empezar a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a9] (a10) {estar a punto de};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a10] (a11) {estar para};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a11] (a12) {estar por};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a12] (a13) {haber (3a persona) + que};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a13] (a14) {haber de};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a14] (a15) {Ir a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a15] (a16) {llegar a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a16] (a17) {meterse a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a17] (a18) {pasar a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a18] (a19) {pensar};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a19] (a20) {ponerse a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a20] (a21) {quedar en};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a21] (a22) {romper a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a22] (a23) {tener que};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a23] (a24) {tratar de};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a24] (a25) {venir a};
    \node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a25] (a26) {volver al}; 

\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[node distance=5mm,
                 every node/.style={align=left,text width=10em,draw}]

\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a26] (b1) {andar}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b1] (b2) {continuar}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b2] (b3) {estar}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b3] (b4) {ir}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b4] (b5) {llevar}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b5] (b6) {quedarse}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b6] (b7) {seguir}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b7] (b8) {venir}; 
\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= b8] (b9) {verse};

\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[node distance=7cm,
                 every node/.style={align=center,text width=2cm,draw}]

    \node[rectangle, right of= a14] (inf) {Infinitivo}; 
    \node[rectangle, right of= b5] (part) {Participio}; 

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd be strongly tempted to create all the nodes in a loop as well.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Would that be possible considering the nodes' content is different?

Comment: Yes.  The first node in a set has to be done manually, but for all the others I would do something like `\foreach[count=\i from 2,count=\prev from 1] \txt in {all,the,nodes,contents} {\node[draw=none,fill=none, below of= a\prev] (a\i) {\txt};}`.  (Haven't checked the syntax - not so used to `\foreach`s.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To automate a process you need to use the `foreach`. In your case it is very simple since you have been very clear in assigning labels to nodes.

You simply have to add to your code:

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,26}
\draw[-stealth] (a\x)--(inf.west);

\foreach \y in {1,...,9}
\draw[-stealth] (b\y)--(part.west);
```